# How to fix the Unknown title issue while opening a file in a SharePoint online library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am noticing a weird issue while opening a PDF file in a Sharepoint online document library. While clicking on the file to open, it opens fine but it says Unknown title where the file name is displayed. See below screenshot.

[image]

Can someone please help me with solving this, I tried renaming the file but the issue still persists for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a SharePoint issue.

You are using the built-in PDF viewer of Chrome.

Download the PDF file and open it using Adobe. File -> Properties -> Check **Title** property.

If the PDF file does not have a Title listed in the Document Properties, it will display either the PDF filename, "Unknown Title", or be blank altogether in Chrome browser (built-in PDF viewer of Chrome).